# C#-WP8: Data Binding in Message Box?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I was showing title name in `TextBlock` in `XAML`. I wanna show this in `MessageBox` when a button Clicked. But I dunno, How to do this ? Any ideas will be appreciated very much. Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
<TextBlock 
Text="{Binding TitleName}" 
FontWeight="Thin" FontSize="28" 
Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-36, 0, 0, 0"/>
```

MessageBox Updation Courtesy : Rakesh R Nair

```
MessageBox.Show("Body of your message", AppDataContext.TitleName, MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

I have Model as `AppDataContext.cs` and i have `public string Password` in that class.

Comment: You are not sure what you are asking for... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to cast your DataContext (which IIRC is of type object) into your real object type in order to use the properties of it.

```
var myBoundObject = DataContext as MyObjectType;
MessageBox.Show("Body of your message", myBoundObject.TitleName, MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

Trying to access the property directly from the DataContext (i.e. `DataContext.TitleName`) will fail.

Note: This assumes that you don't already have an instance of your bound object within the code - this can happen if you are using something like MVVM Light and a ViewModelLocator.  If you do have a reference already, you don't need to cast the DataContext object and can simply access the data from `myExistingObject.TitleName`

Comment: Error 1 : `'AppName.Model.AppDataContext' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`
Error 2 : `The type or namespace name 'MyObjectType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: If the provided solution solve your issue mark it as answered. Else update your current issue you are facing

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, You can simply set the title name in MessageBox, Like this

```
MessageBox.Show("Body of your message", YourObject.TitleName, MessageBoxButton.OK));
```

No matter from where your are setting the TitleName.

Comment: Error `The name 'TitleName' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Here TitleName is the property in your view model or code behind. Can you please add more information that you are trying to achieve

Comment: Where you defined the property? Are you using the same viewmodel for MessageBox & data binding property "TitleName". From your error I believe you defined the property not in viewmodel. You defined the property somewhere else.

Comment: I have `TitleName` in Model. Separate class. I have defined the property in Model only

Comment: So instead of using TitleName directly, use your class object, Suppose u r defined the property in class A. use that class instance (.) property for displaying.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36921/discussion-between-rakesh-r-nair-and-mohamed-thaufeeq)

Comment: i have updated the question by your guidance. Since, it shows error

Comment: You are accessed the property like a static one. which is not possible. You need to use the instance of that class. For example AppDataContext obj = new AppDataContext(); You have done this some where. So use that instance ( like obj.TitleName )

Comment: If the provided solution solve your issue mark it as answered. Else update your current issue you are facing